# oracle sql query - populating values based on priority

Tags: sql, database, oracle

tab1 has details of marks published for students. now all the marks are not out yet , based on empid few are published.

tab1

```
subgrp,empid,sub,marks
1     ,4    ,phy,  90
1     ,4    ,ls ,  44
1     ,5    ,eng,  80
1     ,5    ,eco,  66
```

tab2 has details of all the subjects present in semester along with the priority.

tab2

```
subgrp,sub,priority
1     ,phy,    1
1     ,math,   2
1     ,ls  ,   3
1     ,eng ,   4
1     ,eco,    5
```

tab 1 has details of marks already published for subjects for each of the student.
tab 2 has details of all the subjects present in the subgrp that is in the semister.

i would like to write a query to find out following ..

if you observe closely tab2 is my main table and tab1 is left joined so that i can consider all the values of tab2.

output of the query

```
subgrp,empid,subject,marks,priority
1     ,4    ,phy    ,90   ,1
1     ,4    ,math   ,null ,2
1     ,4    ,ls     ,90   ,3
1     ,4    ,eng    ,null ,4
1     ,4    ,eco    ,null ,5
1     ,5    ,phy    ,null ,1
1     ,5    ,math   ,null ,2
1     ,5    ,ls     ,null ,3
1     ,5    ,eng    ,80   ,4
1     ,5    ,eco    ,66   ,5
```

query i tried to write, incomplete since i am unable to convert the logic into sql..

```
 select a.subgrp,a.emoid , a.sub as subject,a.marks,b.priority from
 tab2 a left join tab1 b on a.subgrp=b.subgrp and a.sub=b.sub
```

i am unable write down the logic, how to populate 5 records for per emp-id based on the tab2 data.

can anyone please help ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the data:

```
select t2.substr, e.empid, t2.subject, t.marks, t2.priority
from (select distinct empid from tab1
     ) e cross join
     tab2 t2 left join
     tab1 t
     on t.empid = e.empid and
        t.subgrp = t2.subgrp and
        t.sub = t2.sub
order by e.empid, t2.priority;
```

Comment: @leftjoin . . . First, the question is tagged Oracle, and it includes Oracle in the title.  So I'm not sure what the reference to Hive is.  The only issue that I could possibly see is that `subgrp` might be used for employees as well.  But the OP doesn't explain that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross join` and then `group by` on it.

```
Select t1.subgrp, 
       t1.empid, 
       t2.subject,
       Max(t1.marks) as marks, 
       t2.priority
  From tab1 t1 cross join tab2 t2
  Group by t1.subgrp, 
           t1.empid, 
           t2.subject, 
           t2.priority
```

Cheers!!